# Manually select one target cell from sheet MS Excel add-in development in C#

Tags: c#, excel-addins

I'm currently developing a MS Excel add-in. I would like to know if it is possible to show a dialog were the user can manually select the target cell just like what you get when executing a function in MS Excel.

[image: Example when trying to execute a function in MS Excel]
I'm new to this Excel add-in development.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the `RefEdit` control is not available in VSTO addin (it is only available for VBA).

However you can achieve a similar  behaviour by playing with the [Application.InputBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.inputbox.aspx) (which open a modal form):

```
Excel.Range rng= ExcelApp.InputBox("Select table range", "", _ 
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 8);
```

see [here](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/wiki/Links-about-RefEdit) for some examples.